# Como puedo guardar una configuracion en laravel en base de datos

Tags: php, laravel

me he descargado una libreria para guardar configuraciones de un proyecto segun la documentacion guardaria en la base de datos como key y value, pero guarda los datos osea los alamacena en algun lado pero no en la base de datos. alguno ya conoce la libreria para poder guardar los datos en la base de datos.

> anlutro/laravel-settings
>   https://packagist.org/packages/anlutro/l4-settings

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.